# Create a method which catches exception if occurred in any of the methods in that class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, method-chaining

I have a class `Demo` which has four methods as below `Add()`, `Update()`, `Delete()` and `Get()`.

And these methods are chained together as below:

```
bool isSuccess = this.Get(1)
                    .Update(200) //new product price
```

Now, I want to implement `CatchError()` method which is going to catch the `Exception if` occurred in any of the above methods.

The code would look as below:

```
bool isSuccess = this.Get(1)
                    .Update(200); //new product price
                    .CatchError();
```

I have `no idea` how to implement`CatchError()` method.

Would be happy to provide additional information to assist the questions properly.

Comment: Would it be a solution to create a `CatchError()` method, where you have an action/Func parameter. And the parameter would be `this.Get(1).Update(200)` . The parameter would look like the one @JeroenMostert wrote in the next comment. --> `() => this.Get(1).Update(200)`

Comment: You can't implement it as a chain on a method. You can, however, implement a method that wraps an `Action`, so you can pass `() => this.Get(1).Update(200)` to it. (While you can technically then chain such an `Action` with an extension method, these tend to obscure more than they clarify.)

Comment: What do all of the methods (`Get`, `Update`, etc.) return?

Comment: All the method returns `this`.

Comment: Why dont you `this.SubscribeOnError(Class_OnError).Get(1).Update(200);` that way you would only need to raise an `CancelEventHandler` in the methods if they give errors.

Comment: @bradbury9 Can you please provide the sample code for the same? Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer without events, but just calling functions @BijayYadav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I wrote in my comment I would try to create a method CatchError() where you give an Action as parameter:

```
bool isSuccess = CatchError(() => Get(1).Update(200));
```

Your CatchError() method would look like this:

```
private static bool CatchError(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: On a further side note, and not really about the actual problem the question asked about (thus, really just a side note): Unless vexing exceptions should be dealt with, catching an exception and completely ignoring the exeception information and the exceptional situation/problem it indicates is usually not a good idea, as one thus loses/ignores information that can be very helpful or is outright essential when troubleshooting problems with the program/software...

Comment: Thats right. So if someone use this code, the exception handling should be made in the catch. That means he should log it, or show it to the user. But I only want to show an opportunity to catch the exceptions with an Method.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you should execute all operations only if CatchError is called. Till it, you should collect all actions that have to be performed.
Something like:

```
public class Demo
{
    private int Value;
    private List<Action> Operations = new List<Action>();
    public Demo Get(int a)
    {
        this.Operations.Add(() => this.Value = a);
        return this;
    }

    public Demo Update(int a)
    {
        this.Operations.Add(() => this.Value += a);
        return this;
    }

    public bool CatchError()
    {
        foreach (var operation in Operations)
        {
            try
            {
                operation();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        Operations.Clear();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if the asker (or somebody else) writes code like `someDemo.Update(...);` without appending `CatchError()`? This approach all too easily leads to writing broken code that is not doing what you might expect when looking at the code...

Comment: IMHO a fluent API should do the actions when calling the methods.

Comment: @elgonzo It depends on, how the whole construct should be used. If the builder pattern will be used, we some "Build"-method will be called on the end, it could be BuildAndCatchError.  Important to know, what exactly this operations are doing and how the results should be accessed.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin, i go with what the method names given in the question imply. Your answer might be a good fit for a different scenario, but it is not a good fit with regard to what we know from the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you create a method in a fluent API to catch the exception you would also need to decide if you want  to continue the execution of the fluent calls. Code following.

If creating a fluent method is not required, I would suggest [Presis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56952632/2265446) because is less complex.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        bool processCancelled = false;
        myCar.SubscribeOnError(CarOnError).Paint(ref processCancelled, "red").Sell(ref processCancelled, 25000d);
    }

    public static bool CarOnError(Exception e)
    {
        // Log exception
        // Decide if must cancel
        return true;
    }
}

public class Car
{
    private Func<Exception, bool> onErrorMethod = null;

    public Car SubscribeOnError(Func<Exception, bool> methodToCall)
    {
        onErrorMethod = methodToCall;
        return this;
    }
    public Car Paint(ref bool cancelled, string color)
    {
        if (cancelled) return this;
        try
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            cancelled = onErrorMethod == null ? true : onErrorMethod(exc);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Car Sell(ref bool cancelled, double price)
    {
        if (cancelled) return this;
        try
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            cancelled = onErrorMethod == null ? true : onErrorMethod(exc);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```